# How can Ashwathama be the next Vyāsa and Saptaṛṣī despite releasing Brahmaśhirā astra on Uttara's womb killing Parikshit?

Tags: mahabharata

[From Viṣṇu   Purāṇa:](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp076.htm)

Ashwathama killed foetus of Parikshit. He was not even born and was in his mother's womb when Ashwathama killed him. How can a person like him compile the vedas in the next Dwapara yuga and even be the next Saptaṛṣī of SUrya Savarni Manvantara.

Comment: For that act he got punishment, right? Even other figures did some kind of sins for that they got punishments and retained/attained titles..

Comment: please vote my question and explain how he will retain or attain posts by doing tapasya, like that

Comment: If Indra can retain his post after so much of nonsense, so I don't see any problem with  Aśvatthāmā being given same treatment.